# can we debug without creating project in code blocks

Tags: c, debugging, codeblocks

I just wanted to ask that can we debug a code without creating a project. I have tried many times but the debugger was not working when I am not under any project.

Comment: I don't see any reqauirement from the C standard to use an IDE at all. Not clear what you mean.

Comment: No sure what you are asking, but there are several debuggers that do not need code blocks to run --- gdb, ollydbg (which is now immunity debugger) etc.

Comment: Dev++ (or the updated fork Orwell Dev-C++) supports debugging a code without creating a project.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging C files alone (without having a project) is not supported by CodeBlocks, you won't find a way with this IDE.